# Cannot step into .NET source code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Environment: W10 Pro x64, Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 5, Class Library project, target framework .NET 4.5.2.

I am trying to step into the .NET source while debugging my code, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work - hitting **F11/Step Into** results in the debugger just going to the next line of my source.  I am trying to step into a call of [`Type.InvokeMember()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/de3dhzwy(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx). In the **Modules** window, I see `mscorlib.dll` has its symbols loaded. One interesting bit of info; not sure if it's relevant or not: the **Path** of `mscorlib.dll` is shown as

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
```

but the **Version** column says

```
4.6.1637.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
```

So **question #1**: is this bad?  (Also, here is the **Symbol Load Information** for `mscorlib.dll`):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage Software\Sage MAS 500 Client\PO\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
C:\Windows\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
C:\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\a41a5f0d874946f7af63753340e70f252\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
C:\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\mscorlib.pdb\a41a5f0d874946f7af63753340e70f252\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
SYMSRV:  C:\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\A41A5F0D874946F7AF63753340E70F252\mscorlib.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/A41A5F0D874946F7AF63753340E70F252/mscorlib.pdb not found
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server. 
SYMSRV:  mscorlib.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 133365 bytes 
http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server. 
C:\Temp\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\A41A5F0D874946F7AF63753340E70F252\mscorlib.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

---

Also, if I hit **F12** when my cursor is on the call to `InvokeMember()`, I get a new "Generated Source File" window with the name `Type [from metadata]` on the window tab. Mousing over the tab gives me the text

```
Preview of C:\Users\conrad\AppData\Local\Temp\6012$CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary$v4.0.30319$NoDynamic\System.Type.cs [from metadata]
```

in the tooltip. There are 3 declarations of `InvokeMember`, for its 3 variants. The one with the most args is marked `abstract` (the version I am using), and the other 2 have the attributes

```
[DebuggerHidden]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
```

So - **question #2** - are these attributes blocking me from stepping into the source? If so, is there a way to override?

It feels like I have looked at about every other SO question on stepping into .NET source, but with no success - here are my Debug options:
[image: VS 2013 Debug Options]

And my Symbol Locations:

[image: Symbol Locations]

Comment: Obvious question:  Do you have the .NET source installed?

Comment: @RayFischer I didn't install anything explicitly. Don't the symbol servers download the source on-demand?

Comment: @Conrad, if you change the .NET Framework version to 4.5.1, how about the result? Please also select "require source files to exactly match the original version", or you could change the symbol catch folder to a new blank path, debug it again.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT no luck after downgrading to 4.5.1 and selecting the "require source..." option.

Comment: @Conrad, Did you debug your app in 64 bit Environment? If you rebuilt project in x86 mode, whether the symbols could be loaded? I mean that you could change the platform target(x86/x64/Any CPU), view the debugging result. Please also check the Debug Modules window and view them easily.

Comment: @Conrad, Not very sure that whether it is related to your local network or others, if you download the symbols from the server, one idea is that you could download them to your local machine, and then load them directly, and then view the result. Maybe we could get useful messages.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT sorry for the delay - holiday weekend and meetings here. I rebuilt the project for x86 (`Platform target: x86`), but still no luck.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT My logging shows symbols are being downloaded from MS - see the **Symbol Load Information** log I posted in the original Q. (Or are you speaking of something different?)

Comment: @Conrad, Do you want to get the source code directly? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html, maybe you could download it directly, and then refer to it, please clean and rebuild your project, debug it again.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I downloaded the 4.5.1 source, and specified all the dirs I thought would be needed in the Solution->Properties->Debug Source Files, cleaned & rebuilt, but still not stepping in.

Comment: @Conrad, I forget those two debugger attributes, if you disable/remove them,  how about the result in your side? To really repro this issue, if possible, you could share the main code with a sample, I will debug it in my side.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT "I forget those two debugger attributes, if you disable/remove them..." -- what debug attribs are you talking about? I'm afraid it won't work to share my code--my project is a class lib (.dll) and the running .exe is a proprietary 3rd-party app. What I'm ultimately trying to do is get more information about the `target` arg to `InvokeMember()` (passed to me by the calling .exe) and hoping to step into .NET code to do that -- so I can't even give you the "correct" args to the method! Given how this is going, I may have to abandon this development direction and search for another.

Comment: @Conrad, I mean the [DebuggerHidden] and [DebuggerStepThrough], sorry for that I didn't find the wrong steps or settings for source code debugging, as you said that it still doesn't work, maybe we would think about the project itself, for example, if your app also use third party dll, do you have the source code for them?

Answer (score 2):

Symbol servers contain ... symbols, not source.

From MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx)

"A program database (.pdb) file, also called a symbol file, maps the identifiers that you create in source files for classes, methods, and other code to the identifiers that are used in the compiled executables of your project. The .pdb file also maps the statements in the source code to the execution instructions in the executables. The debugger uses this information to determine two key pieces of information: the source file and line number that are displayed in the Visual Studio IDE and the location in the executable to stop at when you set a breakpoint. A symbol file also contains the original location of the source files, and optionally, the location of a source server where the source files can be retrieved from."

The symbol servers contain symbols (names of functions, variables etc) they don't contain the source code.  You can find the source code for [mscorlib.dll here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib,namespaces).

Comment: Thanks for the info -- however, I am not seeing where I can download the source files for mscorlib.dll on that site -- is there a link I'm missing? Is there a place in VS to specify a Source Server (as opposed to 'Directories containing source code')?

Comment: Today there is a Download link at the top of the page. It gives you the chance to download ZIP files with all the source for frameworks 4.5.1 - 4.8.